# How to save a R dataframe in msgpack format?

Tags: r, msgpack

I'm looking for a way to save a R dataframe in msgpack format.

With pandas we do that with df.to_msgpack, I've found this https://gist.github.com/abicky/4433343 to read msgpack[1] file in R.

So how to write a R dataframe in msgpack ?

[1]  http://msgpack.org/

Comment: An explanation to understand why this question is off-topic would be very helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an older R-based version for the pre-MsgPack 1.0 format on CRAN: [msgpackR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msgpackR/index.html)

I am using newer (post 1.4.0) MsgPack via headers and C++ bindings, but that packages is so far only in my GitHub repo: [RcppMsgPack](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppmsgpack)

The package is used as an optional compile-time choice for [RcppRedis](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppRedis/index.html).